# Smooth transition from Java to C# (windows mobile)

Tags: c#

could you recommend me the best way to get into C#? As i know Java and those two share many similarities, I"m not very fond of idea of picking a fat book and reading basic concepts. If there is a good thin book ar any good tutorials around, please let me know.

And one more thing I"m interested particularly in Windows mobile development, so no ASP .NET or Windows programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Grab [Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone](http://www.microsoft.com/express/phone/)
- Read "[Getting Started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402529(VS.92).aspx)"
- [Learn about the differences.](http://rayli.net/blog/2008/04/top-10-differences-between-java-and-c/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the source.  The MS developer network.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/bb250560.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Great short tutorial here:

http://www.csharp-station.com/

Good Luck!

Comment: That link gives me a server error.

Comment: @buckbova, the link is back up.  Just wanted to let you know in-case you wanted to take a look.  Again, good luck!